# Best font for POS printer in WPF C# App

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, point-of-sale

I have developed an application in WPF and C# as client requirement. Now I am facing problem in bill printing. Printer is WEP DR-400 series and I am using "FlowDocument" to preview bill and printing. Now my client wants these issue to solve;

1. Printing is slow than previous Foxpro based app
2. Numbers printed on bill creates confusion like 8,9 and 6 appears quite same.

I don't know how to solve these problems, for 2. i have "MS Gothic" with 12 then "Segoe" with 13 font size in FlowDocument after client request. My font selection is constrained by page width (i need to print 5 cols with Item Name which should be displayed in one line).

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

POS printers are almost exclusively used in their native dot-matrix mode.  You send the strings to print directly to the printer, bypassing the printer driver.  The font you'll get is the one that's baked into the printer's firmware.  Typically mono-spaced and optimized to work well with the rather restricted output capabilities of a typical POS printer.  The code you need is in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091).

When you use the printer driver, the printer is switched into graphics mode by the driver.  That makes them *very* slow.

Answer (score -1):

With regard fonts, Georgia is good in distinguishing digits at small point sizes. (Although at 13 points, you shouldn't get a problem with any font.)

As a fully interpreted language, FoxPro is not terribly quick although runtime has a low memory footprint. Could your client benefit from more memory?